# dependency of dependency must be declared in root WORKSPACE?

Tags: bazel

I've written an example:

```
git clone git@github.com:rynz/test-app.git
bazel test //...
```

It will error, complaining that `com_google_absl` could not be resolved.

Edit `WORKSPACE` and uncomment `com_google_absl` dependency, now it will build and test successfully.

`rynz_app` only depends on `rynz_protocol`, however, `rynz_protocol` also depends on `com_google_absl`. Why do I have to redeclare `com_google_absl` within `rynz_app` `WORKSPACE` when it is already declared in `rynz_protocol` `WORKSPACE`?

Kind regards,

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Bazel only reads dependencies listed in your WORKSPACE file. If your
>   project (A) depends on another project (B) which list a dependency on
>   a third project (C) in its WORKSPACE file, you’ll have to add both B
>   and C to your project’s WORKSPACE file. This requirement can balloon
>   the WORKSPACE file size, but hopefully limits the chances of having
>   one library include C at version 1.0 and another include C at 2.0.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#transitive-dependencies